# Fill area between two functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def domain():
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)

    f1 = lambda x: (2*x - x**2)**0.5
    plt.plot(x, f1(x), label = '$y = \sqrt{2x - x^2}$')
    plt.plot(f1(x), x, label = '$x = \sqrt{2y - y^2}$')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.legend(loc='best')


    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_xlim([0, 5])
    axes.set_ylim([0, 5])
    plt.show()

domain()
```

[image]

How can I make use of the [`fill_between()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=fill_between#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) to fill the area between the 2 lines? In other words, how can I fill the small flower petal between the green and blue lines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@user 5061 was right on the code, inverse function was off there

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def domain():
    x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.001)

    f1 = lambda x: (2*x - x**2)**0.5
    f2 = lambda x: 1 - (1-x*x)**0.5 # other part is f2 = lambda x: 1 + (1-x*x)**0.5
    plt.plot(x, f1(x), label = '$y = \sqrt{2x - x^2}$')
    plt.plot(f1(x), x, label = '$x = \sqrt{2y - y^2}$')
    plt.fill_between(x, f1(x), f2(x), where=f1(x)>=f2(x), interpolate=True, color='yellow')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.legend(loc='best')


    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_xlim([0, 5])
    axes.set_ylim([0, 5])
    plt.show()

domain()
```

Not taking the positive component `1 + (1-x*x)**0.5` since it doesn't affect the intersection.

[image]

Comment: I understand you expressed y in terms of x in f2, however, you have 2 possible expressions, no? Based on what did you choose the expression with +?

Comment: `1 + (1-x*x)**0.5` is always `>1` for `0<x<1`, so the deduction to use `1 - (1-x*x)**0.5`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `fill_between()` and fill between your two lines when a condition is met.

[image]

(I altered a bit your code, since the way you wrote it i had to find the inverse function of `f1`)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def domain():
    x = np.arange(0, 2, 0.001)

    f = lambda x: x**0.5
    g = lambda x: x**2
    plt.plot(x, f(x), label = '$y = \sqrt{2x - x^2}$')
    plt.plot(x, g(x), label = '$x = \sqrt{2y - y^2}$')
    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.legend(loc='best')

    plt.fill_between(x, f(x), g(x),where=f(x) > g(x))

    axes = plt.gca()
    axes.set_xlim([0, 2])
    axes.set_ylim([0, 2])

    plt.show()

domain()
```