# Can I plot the error band using the uncertainties of curve fitting (Python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, curve-fitting

Here's the least-square quadratic fitting result of my data: y = 0.06(+/- 0.16)x**2-0.65(+/-0.04)x+1.2(+/-0.001). I wonder is there a direct way to plot the fit as well as the error band? I found a [similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29587827/fill-area-between-two-functions) which used `plt.fill_between` method. However, in that example the boundaries are known, while in my case I'm not quite sure about the exact parameters which correspond to the boundaries. I don't know if I could use `plt.fill_between` or a different approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`seaborn.regplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.regplot.html) to calculate the fit and plot it directly (`order=2` is second order fit):

Here is a dummy example:

```
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

xs = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
ys = xs**2+xs+1+np.random.normal(scale=20, size=50)

sns.regplot(x=xs, y=ys, order=2)
```

[image: seaborn regplot]

Comment: I think this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22852244/how-to-get-the-numerical-fitting-results-when-plotting-a-regression-in-seaborn) are important acknowledge with this answer, just to help OP understand since OP already has the fit and error.